# what is the category parameter in define a receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I know that when I define a Broadcast receiver from manifest in bellow of intent filter I can define **category** that it's optional.

```
<receiver android:name=".PushMessageReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
          <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
          <category android:name="com.test.myAppname" />
          <action android:name="com.test.client.MSGRECEIVE" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I googled but cant get it what is the exact point of adding **category** or how I can use it. I appreciate to give me some examples.

Answer (score -3):

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
/**
 * send
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String MY_ACTION = "com.chaowen.action.MY_ACTION";
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent();
                intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
                //Intent message
                intent.putExtra("msg", "ha ha");
                //send
                sendBroadcast(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
/**
 * receive    
 *
 */
public class MyReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //get Intent message
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button
    android:text="send..."
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.chaowen"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
       <receiver
          android:name="MyReceive"
          >
          <intent-filter>
             <action
               android:name="com.chaowen.action.MY_ACTION" />
          </intent-filter>
          </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Category：
　　　 1. CATEGORY_DEFAULT：default way in android, use as common Activity.
　　　 2.CATEGORY_HOME：set as Home Activity.
　　　 3.CATEGORY_PREFERENCE：set as Preference.　
　　　 4.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER：set to the highest level Activity,usually used with ACTION_MAIN.
　　　 5.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE：set this can be launched by browser.
　　　 6.CATEGORY_GADGET：set this can be in another Activity.

Comment: please show me how can use it. although you know I used my own category. so what is it benefit?